# A question regarding the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, self-study

I would appreciate if you could please take a look at the following attempt. I am preparing for an upcoming exam, and this is taken from a past exam paper. I would like to know if it is correct. Thank you for your time.

Consider the average $Y$ of $n$ independent random variables, each uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Find $n$ so that the probability that $Y$ is smaller than $0.51$ is about $0.98$. Make use of the following values of the cumulative distribution function $\Phi$ of the standard normal distribution. $\Phi(0)=0.50000$, $\Phi(0.5)=0.6915$, $\Phi(1)=0.8413$, $\Phi(1.5)=0.9332$, $\Phi(2)=0.9772$.

**Attempt**

$Y= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}}{n}$, where $Y_{i}$, $i=1, 2, ..., n$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then $\mu = E[Y_{i}]=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma^{2}=Var(Y_{i})=\frac{1}{12}$.

We have
$$Z_{n}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)n}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{12}}}.$$

Then $$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}}{n}=\dfrac{Z_{n}}{\sqrt{12n}} + \dfrac{1}{2}.$$

Now, by the central limit theorem we have
$$P(Y \lt 0.51) = P\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}}{n} \lt 0.51\right)=P\left(\dfrac{Z_{n}}{\sqrt{12n}} + \dfrac{1}{2} \lt 0.51 \right),$$

rearranging, we get

$$P\left(Z_{n} \lt  \sqrt{12n} \left(0.51 - \frac{1}{2} \right)\right).$$

we want $P(Y \lt 0.51) \approx 0.98$, then

$$P\left(Z_{n} \lt  \sqrt{12n} \left(0.51 - \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) \approx 0.98 \Rightarrow P\left(Z_{n} \lt  \sqrt{12n} \left(0.51 - \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) \approx \Phi(2),$$

hence $$\sqrt{12n} \left(0.51 - \frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 2.$$

Solving, we get $n \approx 3333.33 $, which is not a whole number, therefore we take $n = 3334$.

Comment: Though I haven't checked every single step, the reasoning appears sound. That makes the question rather hard to answer with anything but "yes". But I'll add a challenge (hoping your course is not entirely theoretical): can you imagine a way of checking (by using a computer) whether your final answer, 3334, is right, without advanced reasoning or maths?

Comment: @NickSabbe Thank you for your comment. I would probably try a computer simulation, but I have not tried any statistics simulation software. I know a bit of Matlab, but have only used it for pure mathematics questions.

Comment: There's no sense fussing about six digits or even four digits of precision in $n$ when $\Phi$ is given only to one or two digits of precision.  (A more accurate answer is $3515$, showing that even the second digit in $n$ is incorrect.)